# regex split for non-escaped chars only

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string that I need to split on certain characters but not if they are escaped. So far I used regex but realized I get in trouble if the escape char itself is escaped. So if : is the split char and ? the escape char I would expect this behavior

```
a:b?:c??:d???:e????:f
```

becomes

```
a
b?:c??
d???:e????
f
```

Bottomline:

- split must only happening if : is preceeded by an even number of ? or none ?
- all ? must be kept.

Any idea?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8wOmPO/1)

```
(?<!\?)(?:\?{2})*\K:
```

Other variations:

```
(?:^|[^?])(?:\?{2})*\K:       Doesn't use lookbehind
(?<=(?:^|[^?])(?:\?{2})*):    Doesn't use \K, uses variable length lookbehind
```

#### Explanation

- `(?<!\?)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes doesn't match `?`
- `(?:\?{2})*` Match `??` any number of times
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the pattern. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `:` Match this literally

---

## Edit

In the comments under my answer the OP mentioned that the language used is [java](/questions/tagged/java). Since Java doesn't support `\K` or variable width lookbehinds, I've decided to use regex (and the [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object's [`end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end(int)) method) with the [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method.

#### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/x9ObjM)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{

    private static List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        String str = "a:b?:c??:d???:e????:f";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\?)(?:\\?{2})*:");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            result.add(str.substring(getLastIndex(), matcher.end() - 1));
            indices.add(matcher.end());
        }
        result.add(str.substring(getLastIndex()));
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    private static int getLastIndex() {
        if(indices.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return indices.get(indices.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

1. Loop over matches for the regex pattern `(?<!\?)(?:\?{2})*:`.
2. Get the substring from the previous index (or `0` if it doesn't exist) to `Matcher.end()` and add it to the `result` list.
3. Add `Matcher.end()` (for the current match) to the `indices` list.
4. After the above loop finishes, get the substring from the last obtained index in the `indices` list to the end of the string and add it to the `result` list.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer :)

Comment: I should have said, its in Java. No support of \K there.
But awesome quick answer. I wish I'd speak regex natively.

Answer (score 1):

without lookbehind or  \K you can use `(([^\?])(\?{2})*)(:)` but it saves the non-':' part of the match in a group:

[image: example]

Comment: Could you post your answer as a text instead of an image of a text?

Comment: Fair point, added!